# How to remove linked project in AppCode?

Tags: appcode

The title says it all.

`File > Add > Linked project` takes you one way.
Where is the way back?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there simply is no way to do so.

A workaround is to open the file in XCode and `right-click > delete > only remove reference`.